# Zipping and deleting files with certain age

Tags: linux, find, backup

i'm trying to elaborate a command that will find files that haven't been modified in over 6 months and zip them with one command. Afterwards i want to delete all those files and i just archived.

My current command to find the directories with the files is

```
find /var/www -type d -mtime -400 ! -mtime -180 | xargs ls -l > testd.txt
```

This gave me all the directories including the files that are older than 6 months
Now i was wondering if there was a way of zipping all the results and deleting them afterwards. Something amongst the line of

```
find /var/www -type f -mtime -400 ! -mtime -180 | gzip -c archive.gz
```

If anyone knows the proper syntax to achieve this i'd love to know. Thakns!

Edit, after a few tests this command results in a corrupted file

```
find /var/www -mtime -900 ! -mtime -180 | xargs tar -cf test4.tar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: gzip only compresses individual files. it's NOT like pkzip that can bundle multiple files into a single zip archive. You need to tar AND gzip if you want to make a single file compressed archive. gzip will also remove the original uncompressed file, so `gzip foo.txt` will result in there being `foo.txt.gz` on the drive, and `foo.txt` won't exist anymore.

Comment: Would you happen to know what kind of syntax that implies in this current scenario?

Comment: `find ... | xargs gzip` or `find ... -exec gzip {}`

Comment: ok im trying 
find /var/www -type f -mtime -400 ! -mtime -180 | xargs tar -cf test.tar *

Comment: Once i have all my files zipped, can i just add | xargs rm -R *.*
?
Or will that delete my whole server

Comment: don't put * at the end. that'll wildcard match anything in the current directory and pass it to tar, which will probably include files you DON'T want tarred up.

Comment: be VERY VERY careful with that. yes, it can nuke your whole server if you're not careful.

Comment: Okay thakns a lot, i just cancelled the running one and re-started it without the wildcard, we'll see the result soon

Comment: It seems it only took the content of 1 directory and ignored lots of other files and directories that were old. Im trying again without the -type f parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break this into several distinct steps that you can implement and thoroughly test separately:

1. Build a list of files to be archived and then deleted, saved to a temp file
2. Use the list from step 1 to add the files to .tar.gz archives. Give the archive file a name following a specific pattern that won't appear in the files to be archived, and put it in a directory outside the hierarchy of files being archived.
3. Read back the files from the .tar.gz and compare them (or their hashes) to the original files to ENSURE that you got them all without corruption
4. Use the list from step 1 to delete the files.  Do not use a wildcard for deletion.  Put in some guard code to prevent deletion of any file matching the name pattern of the archive .tar.gz file(s) created in step 2.

When testing a script that can do irreversible damage, always code the dangerous command with a leading `echo` and leave it that way until you are sure everything works.  Only then remove the `echo`.

Comment: I did a mistake in one of my commands and it literally zipped EVERY SINGLE FILE on my server, so now im having headaches making it boot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `zip`, it should meet your requirements.

```
find ... | zip -m@ archive.zip
```

> -m (move) deletes the input directories/files after making the specified zip archive.
>
> -@ takes the list of input files from standard input.

You may find more options which are useful to you in the `zip` manual, e. g.

> -r (recurse) travels the directory structure recursively.
>
> -sf (show-files) shows the files that would be operated on, then exits.
>
> -t or --from-date operates on files not modified prior to the specified date.
>
> -tt or --before-date operates on files not modified after or at the specified date.

This could possibly make `find`expendable.

```
zip -mr --from-date 2012-09-05 --before-date 2013-04-13 archive /var/www
```